# Windows 7 SP1 on VMware, fresh installation, same winsxs size after updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vmware, winsxs

The size of my Windows 7 SP1 instance on VMware is getting huge, and a considerable part of it is the winsxs directory.

If I create a fresh Windows 7 SP1 instance, and allow Windows to install the Automatic Updates, will it just end up being the same size as the original?  Is there any point going through the hassle of having to set up a new machine?

(From the limited playing, I'm not a fan of Windows 8 or 8.1, although I know this is an obvious solution.  I'd like to stay on Win7 if possible)

Answer (score 1):

The size will be smaller, because the replaced updates will not be installed again.

You can also redcue the size of the current Windows 7 by [installing this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386) and run Disk Cleanup and select "Windows Update Cleanup":

[image]

[image]

After a reboot the old updates are removed and WinSxS will be cleaned up.

[image]

Comment: Thanks magic - sorry for the delay in getting back to you, work has seriously gotten in the way!  I hadn't thought about replaced updates - however, I would imagine that the difference would be negligible.  I already have that "cleanup" update (at least the KB is in my list of updates) but the "Windows Update Cleanup" is not an option - I will try and see if I can update the update.

Comment: if you can't see the option, there are no replaced updates which can be removed. In this case you can't shrink the WinSxS folder.